# Why can't I "Copy a Data Path"?

Tags: drivers

I'm sorry this question won't be very clear but i really can't understand why i can't "Copy Data Path".

[image]

I can't even select him although i correctly paste data before.
[image]

What could be wrong??

Comment: The red in the datapath property box in your first image indicates the driver variable target doesn't have a valid data_path, and hence there is nothing to copy, this is where you more usually paste a data_path, like the one in your second image once copied

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand your point

Comment: @batFINGER Are you going to write up an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to say it is because it is a bad idea to copy the data path for the driver's expression.  (but only the last half is true, it's not the reason for the menu being non-functional).

You probably want to go through the UI for an element whose property you want to use in the driver (like maybe object location) and copy its data path and paste it into the property path of the driver.

I vaguely recall there are some places in the UI which actually do have a data path, but whose "copy data path" operation is not functional.  This is usually because it's a little too tricky for blender to keep track of it and you'll need the help of an experienced human to figure it out.

Nothing is more frustrating to a new blender python programmer than the "..." that appears in the mouseover readout of a field.

Comment: If you can endure a video tutorial https://youtu.be/Ht4m5txvWos?t=7m6s has an example of using copy data path to set the driver's RNA pointer.

Comment: +1 for "Nothing is more frustrating to a new blender python programmer than the "..." that appears in the mouseover readout of a field.". Really don't get it why this is designed like that.